# Channels over promisses. Why and how to use?

Tags: asynchronous, promise, service-worker, clojurescript, channel

I confess that I haven't study `core.async` yet. I.e. I don't know the **clojure way** to work asynchronously, but I know that is mostly using channels. I work mainly in clojurescript and I'm going to start writing a service worker.

I found [this library](https://github.com/jamesmacaulay/cljs-promises/blob/master/README.md) to write promises as channels, but it feels there is not a lot of work to do without using the library or not.

So, should I use channels over promises in any situation?

Is there a simple convertion from promises to `core.async` using channels?

Comment: Does someone has a side by side example of something implemented using js promises and the same thing implemented using channels?

Answer (score 0):

If you look over the original rational for core.async, it becomes clearer when it has advantages over using another thread such as with `future`.  ClojureScript was one of the big drivers, since it is single-threaded and there is no other options.

Some resources:

- https://clojure.org/news/2013/06/28/clojure-clore-async-channels
- https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/examples/walkthrough.clj
- https://cognitect.com/videos.html  (2 on CLJS core.async)
- https://github.com/cognitect/async-webinar
- https://rigsomelight.com/drafts/clojurescript-core-async-todos.html
- https://medium.com/@loganpowell/cljs-core-async-101-f6522faf536d

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. It's good to back answers with links, but please write in the post itself what these resources state about channels vs promises.